# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - Don't see how this is possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and have read some other examples of this error but cant seem to wrap my head around it.
Here is my dummy data.

I created a table and named it blogPosts

```
CREATE TABLE blogPosts (
    blog_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    author_id INT DEFAULT 1,
    blog_title VARCHAR(200),
    date_created DATE,
    genre VARCHAR(20)
);
```

I then Created a table and named it author:

```
CREATE TABLE author (
    author_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    author_name VARCHAR(75)
);
```

I then created a Foreign Key for blogPosts which referenced the author table by author_id and it worked without problems!

```
ALTER TABLE blogPosts ADD FOREIGN KEY(author_id)
REFERENCES author(author_id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

[image]

Here is my problem though. When I created this new table called genres, I tried to do the same thing and create a foreign key from blogPosts and link it with the primary key of the genres table, but it failed.

```
  CREATE TABLE genres(
        genre_name VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY
    );
ALTER TABLE blogPosts ADD FOREIGN KEY(genre) REFERENCES genres(genre_name) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

**ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dunder_mifflin`.`#sql-6454_2c`, CONSTRAINT `blogposts_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`genre`) REFERENCES `genres` (`genre_name`) ON DELETE SET NULL)**

I really have no idea why this is happening. Any advice would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: If you already have values in `blogPosts.genre`, those values must be in `genres.genre_name` before you can create the FK.

Comment: @Uueerdo Mind blown bro. I would not have figured that on my own. So from now on, if I want to create a foreign key to link tables, the table I am linking too must have the values populated already before I can proceed. OK!

Comment: Yes, it won't create the foreign key constraint if the data already present would violate that constraint.

Comment: @noobcoderiam What's so mind blown about it?  Isn't that the purpose of the `FOREIGN KEY`?  To prevent user from entering whatever values they want.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to run fine on MySQL , here's the dbfiddle for it:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9d76943aacfd4acbe84dd060dbfa7c59

```
CREATE TABLE blogPosts (
    blog_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    author_id INT DEFAULT 1,
    blog_title VARCHAR(200),
    date_created DATE,
    genre VARCHAR(20)
);
CREATE TABLE author (
    author_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    author_name VARCHAR(75)
);

ALTER TABLE blogPosts ADD FOREIGN KEY(author_id)
REFERENCES author(author_id) ON DELETE SET NULL;

CREATE TABLE genres(
        genre_name VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY
    );

ALTER TABLE blogPosts ADD FOREIGN KEY(genre) REFERENCES genres(genre_name) ON DELETE SET NULL;

insert into author(author_name) values ('Ritchie');

insert into genres (genre_name) values ('CS');


insert into blogPosts (author_id, blog_title, genre) values (1, 'Give me a beer, but not a Corona', 'CS');


select * from blogPosts;

select * From author;

select * From genres;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL (normally**) attempts to enforce a foreign key constraint when the constraint is created. If there is data already present in the referencing field(s), the referenced field(s) must contain those combinations of values or the constraint cannot be enforced.

** Disabling `foreign_key_checks` may allow the creation of constraints without making sure there is referenced data present, but re-enabling them will not attempt to enforce any violations of the constrain after the face, leaving your data in a somewhat unreliable state (won't actually conform to the constraint).

Comment: which order would you run those commands in? Even when I populate genres first then populate blogPosts it fails. I thought I understood but I guess I was wrong lol

Comment: I would not recommend disabling foreign key checks for something like this, if the data is present in genre.genre_name before the constraint on blogPosts is added, you should not be having a problem. Do you get a different error message after ensuring the data is present? Also, double check to make sure the referenced and referencing fields have matching/compatible types.

Comment: It's the same error which is weird. I created the genres and authors table first this time. The inserted the data into those tables. Then I created the blogPosts table with foreign keys which works, but when I try to insert data I get that same error message again.

Comment: Append the revised set of sql statements to your question. Include the full creates and inserts in the order they are executed.

Comment: it worked actually, i think i had a typo during the inerstion of data that was causing it - but you were right the first time and i did understand what you said. I appreciate your help :)